# How do i make it so a player can talk to a bot on roblox?

Tags: roblox

I want to make it so after someone spawns they can look at a NPC and hold "E" then after they do that i want a screen gui to appear and tell them what they need to do. i want it so after they are done reading they can click "DONE" and the gui will dissapear. please help me with this code.

Answer (score 2):

> they can look at a NPC and hold "E"

Try using a [ProximityPrompt](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/ProximityPrompt) for this. As 1BL1ZZARD said, you could use Dialogs for the

> i want a screen gui to appear and tell them what they need to do. i want it so after they are done reading they can click "DONE"

However, you could also use a ScreenGui with the ProximityPrompt and make it Enabled with `ProximityPrompt.Triggered:Connect`.

Answer (score 0):

Would these answer your question? https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Usage-of-dialogs / https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Designing-a-Dialog-Tree